# Set a variable react-native-calendars on daypress

Tags: react-native

Im learning react-native and im building a really simple calendar app.

For now my goal is just to set a variable with the day that user presses with ondayPress parameter and display on Text component. And I have the following:

```
const [selectedDay, setSelectedDay] = useState(0);

return(
    <Calendar
        style={styles.calendar}
        onDayPress={(day) => {
           () => setSelectedDay(day.day); 
        }
    />
    <View>
        <Text>{selectedDay}</Text>
    </View>
)
```

But unfortunately it does nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you calling your `setSelectedDay` is wrong.

Change it to

```
onDayPress={(day) => {setSelectedDay(day.day)}}
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.